# How to scale an Image in ImageView to keep the aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-imageview, image-scaling

In Android, I defined an `ImageView`'s `layout_width` to be `fill_parent` (which takes up the full width of the phone).

If the image I put to `ImageView` is bigger than the `layout_width`, Android will scale it, right? But what about the height? When Android scales the image, will it keep the aspect ratio?

What I find out is that there is some white space at the top and bottom of the `ImageView` when Android scales an image which is bigger than the `ImageView`. Is that true? If yes, how can I eliminate that white space?

Answer (score 893, accepted):

1. Yes, by default Android will scale your image down to fit the ImageView, maintaining the aspect ratio. However, make sure you're setting the image to the ImageView using `android:src="..."` rather than `android:background="..."`. `src=` makes it scale the image maintaining aspect ratio, but `background=` makes it scale *and* distort the image to make it fit exactly to the size of the ImageView. (You can use a background and a source at the same time though, which can be useful for things like displaying a frame around the main image, using just one ImageView.)
2. You should also see `android:adjustViewBounds` to make the ImageView resize itself to fit the rescaled image. For example, if you have a rectangular image in what would normally be a square ImageView, adjustViewBounds=true will make it resize the ImageView to be rectangular as well. This then affects how other Views are laid out around the ImageView.

   Then as Samuh wrote, you can change the way it default scales images using the `android:scaleType` parameter. By the way, the easiest way to discover how this works would simply have been to experiment a bit yourself! Just remember to look at the layouts in the emulator itself (or an actual phone) as the preview in Eclipse is usually wrong.

Comment: Thanks. But what if I have an ImageView, and I set the image by using imageView.setImageBitmap()?

Comment: That's the same thing, just done in code rather than XML. `setImageBitmap` is the same as `android:src="..."` and `setBackground...` is `android:background="..."`

Comment: @SteveHaley i know it is too late but can you please tell me image.setImageDrawable equivalent in xml code

Comment: @SuperUser `image.setImageDrawable(...)` is `android:src="..."` in xml aswell.

Comment: "android:adjustViewBounds" is the handy one here to note! 
if you do not add this, you most likely will have issues with the ImageView border/bounds/container not scaling correctly.

Comment: <code>android:scaleType="fitCenter"</code> Also seem to work well. It automatically crops such that image fully fits the Image view.

Comment: Be aware that adjustViewBounds would not work in case ImageView has exact size specified in layout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022841/when-will-measurespec-unspecified-and-measurespec-at-most-be-applied

Comment: Spot on ! Brilliant answer ...saved a lot of coding...i was going for a custom imageview..thanks a lot !

Comment: It's awesome! I find your answer for along time. Before that I used adjustViewBounds and setBackground, It wasn't working as well.

Comment: src= vs background= was the difference for me!

Comment: `android:adjustViewBounds` was the last piece to my puzzle, thanks!

Comment: Correct answer but I withheld my +1 because IMO your verbosity was unwarranted for this question. Regardless, thank you for your time.

Comment: android:adjustViewBounds="true" finally fixed it for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 314):

See [`android:adjustViewBounds`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds).

> Set this to true if you want the ImageView to adjust its bounds to preserve the aspect ratio of its drawable.

Comment: This is the correct fix for the issue. We were having this on our image view, where the height included all of this extra whitespace. It isn't "transparent pixels", since we had fill_parent for width, and wrap_content for height. If you don't have adjustViewBounds=true, then you get the extra whitespace. After setting that to true, our issue went away. Thanks!

Comment: thanks, this and setting it to src instead of background worked perfectly!

Comment: See also [how-to-scale-bitmap-to-screen-size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410364/how-to-scale-bitmap-to-screen-size)

Comment: This is the perfect fix for the issue. Also for the sizes, use the parent container to set the size, and set match_parent in the ImageView. This solves a lot of troubles.

Comment: +1 for getting to the point. I initially wrote that in a more "colloquial" phrase and sof barred me from submitting it. Rather than ruffle feathers a went PC.

Answer (score 209):

To anyone else having this particular issue. You have an `ImageView` that you want to have a width of `fill_parent` and a height scaled proportionately:

Add these two attributes to your `ImageView`:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

And set the `ImageView` width to `fill_parent` and height to `wrap_content`.

Also, if you don't want your image to be cropped, try this:

```
 android:adjustViewBounds="true"
 android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Comment: Yes but your image gets cropped. The perfect solution would stretch to width, maintain aspect ratio and not crop. I have no idea why this has to be so anoing to do...

Comment: Me either :( Sorry if my solution did not help you, but it did help me.

Comment: Kevin, what you said was exactly what i was looking for, if the size of the image is less than that of the screen, it gets zoomed in and centered, perfect. Thanks.

Comment: +1, except for "(or other `View`)". AFAICT no other view has `adjustViewBounds` or `scaleType` attributes.

Comment: how about using android:scaleType="centerInside" instead of android:scaleType="centerCrop"? It would also not crop the image but ensure that both width and height are less than or equal the imageview's width and height :)
Here's a good visual guide for scaletypes: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide

Comment: @vida I looked through all of these and other questions, and this was the solution that worked for me.  It involved no converting and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 59):

If you want an `ImageView` that both scales up and down while keeping the proper aspect ratio, add this to your XML:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

Add this to your code:

```
// We need to adjust the height if the width of the bitmap is
// smaller than the view width, otherwise the image will be boxed.
final double viewWidthToBitmapWidthRatio = (double)image.getWidth() / (double)bitmap.getWidth();
image.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (bitmap.getHeight() * viewWidthToBitmapWidthRatio);
```

It took me a while to get this working, but this appears to work in the cases both where the image is smaller than the screen width and larger than the screen width, and it does not box the image.

Comment: Why not just use android:scaleType="centerCrop"?

Comment: works like a charm, thanks. scaleType depend on situation, for example i needed exactly this.

Comment: This's a little bit barbarian way of resizing the view. What happens if the view bounds change after you set the bitmap to the ImageView? This's why it should be done in onMeasure(), which can be implemented if you make a custom subclass of ImageView.

Comment: All I needed was the fitCenter and adjustViewBounds, the rest of the code at least for me was unnecessary

Comment: This works for me and don't need to add any code. Without the adjustViewBounds if the image width was smaller than imageView width, it was not scaling up, so the height was stopping to the native height and on the width some bands did appear.

Answer (score 18):

This worked for me:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:maxWidth="39dip"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:adjustViewBounds ="true"
```

Answer (score 12):

This is how it worked for me inside a ConstraintLayout:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImg"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

Then in code, I set the drawable as:

```
ImageView imgView = findViewById(R.id.myImg);
imgView.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.image_to_show, null));
```

This fits the image nicely according to its aspect ratio and keeps it in centre.

Answer (score 11):

this solved my problem

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: It doesn't preserve the aspect ratio of the image for me.

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at [ImageView.ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) to control and understand the way resizing happens in an `ImageView`. When the image is resized (while maintaining its aspect ratio), chances are that either the image's height or width becomes smaller than `ImageView`'s dimensions.

Answer (score 9):

Below code Working for scale image as aspect ratio:

```
Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("Your path");
int nh = (int) ( bitmapImage.getHeight() * (512.0 / bitmapImage.getWidth()) );
Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapImage, 512, nh, true);
your_imageview.setImageBitmap(scaled);
```

Answer (score 7):

Use these properties in ImageView to keep aspect ratio:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="fitXY"

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    />
```

Comment: Only this answer helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I have an image smaller than the screen. To have it stretched proportionally to the max and centered in the view I had to use the following code:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

Have in mind though, that if you have a relative layout and have some elements set to be above or below the ImageView, they will be most likely overlapped by the image.

Answer (score 5):

If image quality decreases in: 
use

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

instead of

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone of you who wants the image to fit exact the imageview with proper scaling and no cropping use

```
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

where imageView is the view representing your ImageView

Comment: Nope, this changes the aspect ration. The docs say: "Scale in X and Y independently, so that src matches dst exactly. This may change the aspect ratio of the src."

Comment: By the way, this FIT_XY can not be used for changing the width/height of the image for displaying on the imageview.

Comment: `ScaleType.FIT_XY` does not preserve the aspect ratio. `ScaleType.FIT_XY` will stretch the image to exactly fit the `ImageView` dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate screen width. And you can scale bitmap.

```
 public static float getScreenWidth(Activity activity) {
        Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        display.getMetrics(outMetrics);
        float pxWidth = outMetrics.widthPixels;
        return pxWidth;
    }
```

---

calculate screen width and scaled image height by screen width.

```
float screenWidth=getScreenWidth(act)
  float newHeight = screenWidth;
  if (bitmap.getWidth() != 0 && bitmap.getHeight() != 0) {
     newHeight = (screenWidth * bitmap.getHeight()) / bitmap.getWidth();
  }
```

After you can scale bitmap.

```
Bitmap scaledBitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, (int) screenWidth, (int) newHeight, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

When doing this programmatically, be sure to call the setters in the correct order:

```
imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true)
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want your image occupy the maximum possible space then the best option would be

```
android:layout_weight="1"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

Answer (score 2):

Yo don't need any java code. You just have to :

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

The key is in the match parent for width and height

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/logo"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:scaleType="centerInside"
android:src="@drawable/logo" />
```

Comment: I also set `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`. `centerInside` was the way to go to prevent cropping and maintaining the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `android:layout_gravity` for ImageView:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

The example above worked for me.

Comment: android:layout_weight="1" is the key.

Answer (score 1):

I have an algorithm to scale a bitmap to bestFit the container dimensions, maintaining its aspect ratio. Please find my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503184/android-image-scaling-to-support-multiple-resolutions/22631351#22631351)

Hope this helps someone down the lane!

Answer (score 1):

Pass your ImageView and based on screen height and width you can make it

```
    public void setScaleImage(EventAssetValueListenerView view){
        // Get the ImageView and its bitmap
        Drawable drawing = view.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawing).getBitmap();
        // Get current dimensions
        int width = bitmap.getWidth();
        int height = bitmap.getHeight();

        float xScale = ((float) 4) / width;
        float yScale = ((float) 4) / height;
        float scale = (xScale <= yScale) ? xScale : yScale;

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scale, scale);

        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
        BitmapDrawable result = new BitmapDrawable(scaledBitmap);
        width = scaledBitmap.getWidth();
        height = scaledBitmap.getHeight();

        view.setImageDrawable(result);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = width;
        params.height = height;
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Programatically apply aspect ratio to Imageview:

```
aspectRatio = imageWidth/imageHeight   
ratioOfWidth = imageWidth/maxWidth  
ratioOfHeight = imageHeight/maxHeight  


if(ratioOfWidth > ratioOfHeight){​​​​​​​
    imageWidth = maxWidth 
    imageHeight = imageWidth/aspectRatio
}​​​​​​​ else if(ratioOfHeight > ratioOfWidth){​​​​​​​
    imageHeight = maxHeight
    imageWidth = imageHeight * aspectRatio
}​​​​​​​
```

After that you can use scaled bitmap to image view

```
Bitmap scaledBitmap= Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, (int) imageWidth , (int) imageHeight , true);
```

Answer (score 0):

in case of using `cardview`for rounding `imageview` and fixed `android:layout_height` for header this worked for me to load image with `Glide`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="220dp"
             xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|top"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
            card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <ImageView
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:maxHeight="220dp"
                android:id="@+id/iv_full"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can scale image that will also reduce the size of your image.
There is a library for it you can download and use it.
https://github.com/niraj124124/Images-Files-scale-and-compress.git

How to use
1)Import the compressor-v1.0. jar to your project.
2)Add the below sample code to test.
    ResizeLimiter resize = ImageResizer.build();
    resize.scale("inputImagePath", "outputImagePath",imageWidth, imageHeight);
Many more methods are there according to your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/yourImage"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score -5):

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 130, 110, false));
```