# How to fit GIF file to screen size in android

Tags: android, view, animated-gif

I am playing gif animation file using movie class, but could not fit within the screen.

How to scale or fit gif file to screen size ?

I have taken GIF view custom view and playing animation using Movie class.

Answer (score 5):

Try this GifImageView

## Set Height Width of Movie as screen Height Widht.

```
   init()
    {
        WindowManager wManager = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wManager.getDefaultDisplay();
        float screenwidth = display.getWidth();
        float screenheight = display.getHeight();

        mWidth = (int) screenwidth;
        mHeight = (int) screenheight;

        //Then force invalidated the layout of this view.

        requestLayout();
    }
```

## This method will be called when you call setGifImageResource() from Activity.

Activity will look like below :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myactivity);

        GifImageView gifImageView = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.GifImageView);
        gifImageView.setGifImageResource(R.drawable.my_gif);
    }
```

Again in our custom layout we need following :

## Determine the measured width and height of view.

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {     
        setMeasuredDimension(mWidth, mHeight);
}
```

## Important code while drawing on canvas.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        //Other general code (included in given link)...

        if (mMovie != null) {

            //Other general code (included in given link)...

            canvas.scale((float) this.getWidth() / (float) mMovie.width(),
                    (float) this.getHeight() / (float) mMovie.height());
            mMovie.draw(canvas, 0, 0);          
            invalidate();
        }
}
```

I have customized this view as our requirement.

## check the link below.

https://github.com/NihalPandya/demoUpload/blob/master/GifImageView.java

Answer (score 4):

You Can Do this with this code :

```
    float scaleWidth = (float) ((screenwidth / (1f*gifwidth)));//add 1f does the trick
    float scaleHeight = (float) ((screenheight / (1f*gifheight)));
    canvas.scale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    mMovie.draw(canvas, 0, 0);//mMovie is my gif picture
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a canvas (@surface view) take its height and width in the gameloop and draw the background image with its values.
If not,

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
float tmp = display.getHeight;
```

Now tmp will contain the value of your display height. Same guese for width.
Use those properties to stretch the gif.

However I must say this function is deprecated and there must be a better way, this will work just fine though :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a frame by frame animation instead of animated gif to get similar end result and scaling.
You need to extract each frame from the gif and place individual frames as png(or other supported format) files in the res/drawable folder. Create and use the animation drawable:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html

To scale the animation, 
[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020460/android-how-to-maintain-aspect-ratio-in-animation/20765456#20765456).

There are various [scaleTypes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) you can use to scale your animation using this method.

I know this does not directly answers the question but it will give the desired end result.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look over [here](http://droid-blog.net/2011/10/14/tutorial-how-to-use-animated-gifs-in-android-part-1/). Full tutorial that covers 3 different ways to display/play GIF's. Apparently it's not very easy and there are still open issue reports with google. Good luck :)

Comment: Answers that are basically just a link to another site usually aren't very helpful. Links also go out of date or break, so would you mind summarizing the important bits here instead? Specifically, whichever part of the tutorial addresses GIF scaling, since that's what this question is about.