# How to stretch an image in Android to fullscreen while maintaining aspect ratio?

Tags: android, image, fullscreen, aspect-ratio

As stated in the title I'm having trouble with the first step, which is stretching the image to the screen's resolution. My second problem is maintaining aspect ratio while stretching the image.

My code:

```
TwoDimensionalSprite _2dBckgrndSprite = new TwoDimensionalSprite(_parentScreen.getContext());
_2dBckgrndSprite.setImageResource(R.drawable.oh);//old-house
_2dBckgrndSprite.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

_parentScreen.AddElement(_2dBckgrndSprite);
```

I know of the method setScaleType and I have tried it aswell but nothing seems to work.

Comment: does `TwoDimensionalSprite` extend `ImageView`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of -> <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521959/how-to-scale-an-image-in-imageview-to-keep-the-aspect-ratio">Scale-keep-aspect-ratio</a> See "android:adjustViewBounds"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to scale an Image in ImageView to keep the aspect ratio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521959/how-to-scale-an-image-in-imageview-to-keep-the-aspect-ratio)

Answer (score 0):

Use ScaleType:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Answer (score 0):

using imgview.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

will make the image fit exactly on device.