# How can I scale an image using only one dimension in Android?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am trying to scale an image specifying only the width I want. The height would be scaled in a way that the aspect ratio is preserved. The image I am using is big enough to cover the whole screen. The code I am trying looks like this:

```
<ImageView android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_width="100sp" android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
```

If I use "fitXY" the image doesnt preserve the aspect ratio and when I use "centerInside" the image is not scaled.. Any idea?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410364/how-to-scale-bitmap-to-screen-size/6410419#6410419

Comment: I already got it!! You have to use the properties android:adjustViewBounds="true" and android:scaleType="fitXY".

So the code looks like this:

    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/logo" android:adjustViewBounds="true"
   android:layout_width="100sp" android:id="@+id/imageView1"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scaleType="fitXY" />

Regards!

Comment: Solution in a comment of answer 1

Answer (score 0):

Jesbomar's solution with pretty formatting:

```
<ImageView 
    android:src="@drawable/logo" 
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
    android:layout_width="100sp" 
    android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:scaleType="centerInside" 
    />
```

I prefer scaleType="centerInside" to "scaleXY" to make the image as big as possible without changing the aspect ratio or cropping any part of it.

Thanks for coming back with your solution jesbomar, it was very helpful.