# android - How to cut some part of image and show it in imageview

Tags: android, imageview, scale

I want to show only some part of image in imageview. See following image .
[image: image part]

Same example can be found in google+ app where you see all posts with images.

Any links ,code will be helpful. 
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this code

```
int width = bitmapOrg.width();
int height = bitmapOrg.height();
int newWidth = 200;
int newHeight = 200;

// calculate the scale - in this case = 0.4f
float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

// createa matrix for the manipulation
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
// resize the bit map
matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

// recreate the new Bitmap
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0, 
                  width, height, matrix, true); 

// make a Drawable from Bitmap to allow to set the BitMap 
// to the ImageView, ImageButton or what ever
BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(resizedBitmap);

ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

// set the Drawable on the ImageView
imageView.setImageDrawable(bmd);
```

Comment: how to set newWidth equal to device width so that image will be scaled according to device screen width ?

Comment: int newWidth=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

Comment: btw one problem - it is stretching image I dont want to stretch image, i want to cut the part of image as I shown in example in question.. more commonly I want to crop it :)

Comment: Is this image stretching after setting newWidth equal to Device width or before?

Comment: I need to 1st resize image using ur code with width equal to device width and then use ZuzooVn's code to crop image to cut its height to say 100px..

Comment: that's because your original image width is small in size. if you only want to crop your image from the aspect of height then use int newWidth=bitmapOrg.width();

Comment: one more question .. my image size is 2560 x 1920 .. I want to maintain aspect ratio of image but also want to resize its width to device width , so that it will be still have its aspect ratio after resizing its width to device width .. hope u understand wht i m saying .

Comment: U can find your this question's solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410364/how-to-scale-bitmap-to-screen-size?lq=1)

Answer (score 9):

```
// Set some constants
private static final Bitmap SOURCE_BITMAP = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(....); // Get the source Bitmap using your favorite method :-)
private static final int START_X = 10;
private static final int START_Y = 15;
private static final int WIDTH_PX = 100;
private static final int HEIGHT_PX = 100;

// Crop bitmap
Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(SOURCE_BITMAP, START_X, START_Y, WIDTH_PX, HEIGHT_PX, null, false);

// Assign new bitmap to ImageView
ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view);
image.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
```

Comment: I have tried this but I cant set new image width according to device screen size , see comment no.1 on deepika answer

Comment: Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay(); 
int screenWidth = display.getWidth();

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking to cut image from the bottom

```
// recreate the new Bitmap
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, x, y, 
                  width, height, matrix, true);
```

replace following params with this logic

y : (bitmapOrg.getHeight() - 1) - (height of the red box present in the question)

height : (height of the red box present in the question)

This way you could avoid exceptions such as(for x you need to modify accordingly)

```
IllegalArgumentException: x + width must be <= bitmap.width() in android

IllegalArgumentException: y + width must be <= bitmap.height() in android
```