# How to scale an image to the top center? - Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, imageview, scale

I have an imageview as background. It is bigger than screen. I want to center it horizontally. It should align to the top. So, top of the original image should seen in the screen. I can resize the original images if necessary.

For example, in the giraffe image, I should be able to see from head to neck, not to the foot. Because the width allows that much.

**XML Code**

...

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:src="@drawable/home_screen_wallpaper_image"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Image to what i want when image is too big to phone size, scale should be like this]

Comment: Hi, if you don't mind, could you please add an example of what you need so I can help you if I can.

Comment: I need to set my background image centered horizontally and top start. fitStart make top and left, i need top and center. I update question add a image to explain better.

Comment: This may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837523/android-how-to-cut-some-part-of-image-and-show-it-in-imageview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual scale types will not work for you. You will need to use the [MATRIX](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType#MATRIX) scale type.

Here is how to apply it:

```
binding.matrixImage.doOnNextLayout {
    // We will use a Matrix to shift the image left.
    binding.matrixImage.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX
    
    // Compute how far to shift the image
    val dx = (binding.matrixImage.drawable.intrinsicWidth - binding.matrixImage.width) / 2f
    
    // Create and set the Matrix.
    val matrix = Matrix()
    matrix.postTranslate(-dx, 0f)
    binding.matrixImage.imageMatrix = matrix
}
```