# Fit image into ImageView, keep aspect ratio and then resize ImageView to image dimensions?

Tags: android, imageview, scale

How to fit an image of random size to an `ImageView`?
When:

- Initially `ImageView` dimensions are 250dp *  250dp
- The image's larger dimension should be scaled up/down to 250dp
- The image should keep its aspect ratio
- The `ImageView` dimensions should match scaled image's dimensions after scaling

E.g. for an image of 100*150, the image and the `ImageView` should be 166*250.
E.g. for an image of 150*100, the image and the `ImageView` should be 250*166.

If I set the bounds as

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

images fit properly in the `ImageView`, but the `ImageView` is always 250dp * 250dp.

Comment: Uh, do you mean to change the size of the `ImageView` to the image size? E.g. image of 100dp x 150dp would scale `ImageView` to the same measures? Or do you mean how to scale the image to the `ImageView` bounds. E.g. image of 1000dp x 875dp would be scaled into 250dp x 250dp. Do you need to maintain aspect ratio?

Comment: I want the ImageView to have the dimensions of the image, and the image to have its largest dimension equals to 250dp and to keep its aspect ratio. E.g. for an image of 100*150, I want the image and the ImageView to be 166*250. I'll update my question.

Comment: Do you want to do scaling/adjustment only when displaying an activity (do once) or when doing something on the activity like selecting a picture from gallery/web (do many times but not on load) or both?

Comment: See my modified answer, which should do exactly as you wished it :)

Answer (score 147, accepted):

*(The answer was heavily modified after clarifications to the original question)*

After clarifications:
This **cannot be done in xml only**. It is not possible to scale both the image and the `ImageView` so that image's one dimension would always be 250dp and the `ImageView` would have the same dimensions as the image.

**This code scales** `Drawable` of an `ImageView` to stay in a square like 250dp x 250dp with one dimension exactly 250dp and keeping the aspect ratio. Then the `ImageView` is resized to match the dimensions of the scaled image. The code is used in an activity. I tested it via button click handler.

*Enjoy. :)*

```java
private void scaleImage(ImageView view) throws NoSuchElementException  {
    // Get bitmap from the the ImageView.
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    try {
        Drawable drawing = view.getDrawable();
        bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawing).getBitmap();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("No drawable on given view");
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        // Check bitmap is Ion drawable
        bitmap = Ion.with(view).getBitmap();
    }

    // Get current dimensions AND the desired bounding box
    int width = 0;

    try {
        width = bitmap.getWidth();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Can't find bitmap on given view/drawable");
    }

    int height = bitmap.getHeight();
    int bounding = dpToPx(250);
    Log.i("Test", "original width = " + Integer.toString(width));
    Log.i("Test", "original height = " + Integer.toString(height));
    Log.i("Test", "bounding = " + Integer.toString(bounding));

    // Determine how much to scale: the dimension requiring less scaling is
    // closer to the its side. This way the image always stays inside your
    // bounding box AND either x/y axis touches it.  
    float xScale = ((float) bounding) / width;
    float yScale = ((float) bounding) / height;
    float scale = (xScale <= yScale) ? xScale : yScale;
    Log.i("Test", "xScale = " + Float.toString(xScale));
    Log.i("Test", "yScale = " + Float.toString(yScale));
    Log.i("Test", "scale = " + Float.toString(scale));

    // Create a matrix for the scaling and add the scaling data
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(scale, scale);

    // Create a new bitmap and convert it to a format understood by the ImageView 
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
    width = scaledBitmap.getWidth(); // re-use
    height = scaledBitmap.getHeight(); // re-use
    BitmapDrawable result = new BitmapDrawable(scaledBitmap);
    Log.i("Test", "scaled width = " + Integer.toString(width));
    Log.i("Test", "scaled height = " + Integer.toString(height));

    // Apply the scaled bitmap
    view.setImageDrawable(result);

    // Now change ImageView's dimensions to match the scaled image
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams(); 
    params.width = width;
    params.height = height;
    view.setLayoutParams(params);

    Log.i("Test", "done");
}

private int dpToPx(int dp) {
    float density = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return Math.round((float)dp * density);
}
```

The xml code for the `ImageView`:

```xml
<ImageView a:id="@+id/image_box"
    a:background="#ff0000"
    a:src="@drawable/star"
    a:layout_width="wrap_content"
    a:layout_height="wrap_content"
    a:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    a:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

Thanks to this discussion for the scaling code:
http://www.anddev.org/resize_and_rotate_image_-_example-t621.html

**UPDATE 7th, November 2012:**
Added null pointer check as suggested in comments

Comment: The ImageView will always be 250*250.

Comment: Ok. That cannot be done in xml only. Java code is required. With xml you can either scale the image or the `ImageView`, not both.

Comment: didn't realize you could replace android: with a:

Comment: hi can some one say me what is Ion in the line bitmap = Ion.with(view).getBitmap();

Comment: Ion is a framework for asynchronous networking and image loading:
https://github.com/koush/ion

Comment: Thanks, +1 for you, It really helped me.

Comment: How can we do same thing for view like Relative Layout with maintaining aspect ratio.

Comment: If someone just needs a resized ImageView, you can skip the middle part and just resize the ImageView and after that set the drawable which will adapt to it following its scaleType

Comment: @StackOverflowed you can replace "android:" with anything. You define that term at the top of the XML file with the "xmlns" attribute. It's done that way so that if two different schemas happen to have the same name, and you wanted to use both in the same XML file, you could assign them different prefixes.

Answer (score 291):

May not be answer for this specific question, but if someone is, like me, searching for answer how to fit image in ImageView with bounded size (for example, `maxWidth`) while preserving Aspect Ratio and then get rid of excessive space occupied by ImageView, then the simplest solution is to use the following properties in XML:

```
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Comment: This works if you don't want the image to be scaled up if it is too small.

Comment: how do i scale it up if its too small and also maintain the aspect ratio ?

Comment: if someone needs, "fitCenter" is another attribute for scaleType, and it will not scale up the image, but for any big image, it will fit the maximum size of the image inside the view box maintaining the aspect ratio

Comment: to scale up small images use scaleType="centerCrop" instead.

Comment: one more thing for me to work with this solution is to use "android:src" not the "android:background" to ref my image.

Answer (score 54):

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:scaleType="centerCrop"
           android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

Answer (score 26):

The Below code make the bitmap perfectly with same size of the imageview. Get the bitmap image height and width and then calculate the new height and width with the help of imageview's parameters. That give you required image with best aspect ratio.

```
int currentBitmapWidth = bitMap.getWidth();
int currentBitmapHeight = bitMap.getHeight();

int ivWidth = imageView.getWidth();
int ivHeight = imageView.getHeight();
int newWidth = ivWidth;

newHeight = (int) Math.floor((double) currentBitmapHeight *( (double) new_width / (double) currentBitmapWidth));

Bitmap newbitMap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitMap, newWidth, newHeight, true);

imageView.setImageBitmap(newbitMap)
```

enjoy.

Comment: This will just reduce the original height by the same factor by which the width was reduced. This won't gurantee that newHeight < ivHeight. Ideally you should check which ratio is bigger (currentBitmapHeight /ivHeight , currentBitmapWidth /ivWidth ) and then on the basis of this take further decision.

Comment: This actually works perfectly, although you don't need ivHeight or newWidth, just put ivWidth into the calculation instead.

Answer (score 15):

try adding `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to your `ImageView`.

Comment: This will modify the aspect ratio if the original image is not squared.

Comment: `fitXY` will almost always change the aspect ratio of the image. OP clearly mentions that the aspect ratio MUST be maintained.

Answer (score 11):

this can all be done using XML... the other methods seem pretty complicated.
Anyway, you just set the height to what ever you want in dp, then set the width to wrap content or visa versa. Use scaleType fitCenter to adjust the size of the image.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1">
```

Answer (score 10):

The Best solution that works in most cases is

Here is an example:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/avatar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

Comment: Do not rely on deprecated API (fill_parent)

Comment: how does this answer OP's question. This won't maintain aspet ratio

Answer (score 8):

After searching for a day, I think this is the easiest solution:

```
imageView.getLayoutParams().width = 250;
imageView.getLayoutParams().height = 250;
imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer, But I think it is better to add `adjustViewBounds` to XML

Answer (score 7):

Edited **Jarno Argillanders** answer:
*How to fit Image with your Width and Height:*
1) Initialize ImageView and set Image:

```
iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_image);
iv.setImageBitmap(image);
```

2) Now resize:

```
scaleImage(iv);
```

Edited `scaleImage` method: (*you can replace EXPECTED bounding values*)

```
private void scaleImage(ImageView view) {
    Drawable drawing = view.getDrawable();
    if (drawing == null) {
        return;
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawing).getBitmap();

    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();
    int xBounding = ((View) view.getParent()).getWidth();//EXPECTED WIDTH
    int yBounding = ((View) view.getParent()).getHeight();//EXPECTED HEIGHT

    float xScale = ((float) xBounding) / width;
    float yScale = ((float) yBounding) / height;

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(xScale, yScale);

    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
    width = scaledBitmap.getWidth();
    height = scaledBitmap.getHeight();
    BitmapDrawable result = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), scaledBitmap);

    view.setImageDrawable(result);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams(); 
    params.width = width;
    params.height = height;
    view.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

And .xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Comment: I think this cast:
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams(); 
should go the other way, since MarginLayoutParams inherit from ViewGroup.LayoutParams.

Answer (score 7):

if it's not working for you then replace android:background with android:src

android:src will play the major trick

```
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/bg_hc" />
```

it's working fine like a charm

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use this code:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/avatar"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Answer (score 3):

This did it for my case.

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"         
           android:scaleType="centerCrop"
           android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to have an ImageView and an Bitmap, so the Bitmap is scaled to  ImageView size, and size of the ImageView is the same of the scaled Bitmap :).

I was looking through this post for how to do it, and finally did what I want, not the way described here though.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/acpt_frag_root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/imageBackground"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/acpt_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/document_editor_image_margin"
    android:background="@color/imageBackground"
    android:elevation="@dimen/document_image_elevation" />
```

and then in onCreateView method

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scanner_acpt, null);

    progress = view.findViewById(R.id.progress);

    imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.acpt_image);
    imageView.setImageBitmap( bitmap );

    imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(()->
        layoutImageView()
    );

    return view;
}
```

and then layoutImageView() code

```
private void layoutImageView(){

    float[] matrixv = new float[ 9 ];

    imageView.getImageMatrix().getValues(matrixv);

    int w = (int) ( matrixv[Matrix.MSCALE_X] * bitmap.getWidth() );
    int h = (int) ( matrixv[Matrix.MSCALE_Y] * bitmap.getHeight() );

    imageView.setMaxHeight(h);
    imageView.setMaxWidth(w);

}
```

And the result is that image fits inside perfectly, keeping aspect ratio,
and doesn't have extra leftover pixels from ImageView when the Bitmap is inside.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9VZO.jpg)

It's important ImageView to have 
wrap_content and adjustViewBounds to true,
then setMaxWidth and setMaxHeight will work, this is written in the source code of ImageView,

```
/*An optional argument to supply a maximum height for this view. Only valid if
 * {@link #setAdjustViewBounds(boolean)} has been set to true. To set an image to be a
 * maximum of 100 x 100 while preserving the original aspect ratio, do the following: 1) set
 * adjustViewBounds to true 2) set maxWidth and maxHeight to 100 3) set the height and width
 * layout params to WRAP_CONTENT. */
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to get this done in a constraint layout with Picasso, so I munged together some of the above answers and came up with this solution (I already know the aspect ratio of the image I'm loading, so that helps):

**Called in my activity code somewhere after setContentView(...)**

```
protected void setBoxshotBackgroundImage() {
    ImageView backgroundImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.background_image_view);

    if(backgroundImageView != null) {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        int height = (int) Math.round(width * ImageLoader.BOXART_HEIGHT_ASPECT_RATIO);

        // we adjust the height of this element, as the width is already pinned to the parent in xml
        backgroundImageView.getLayoutParams().height = height;

        // implement your Picasso loading code here
    } else {
        // fallback if no element in layout...
    }
}
```

**In my XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background_image_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        app:srcCompat="@color/background"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <!-- other elements of this layout here... -->

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Note the lack of a constraintBottom_toBottomOf attribute. **ImageLoader** is my own static class for image loading util methods and constants.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a very simple solution. Here my code:

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
imageView.getLayoutParams().height = imageView.getLayoutParams().width;
imageView.setMinimumHeight(imageView.getLayoutParams().width);
```

My pictures are added dynamically in a gridview. When you make these settings to the imageview, the picture can be automatically displayed in 1:1 ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Use Simple math to resize the image . either you can resize `ImageView` or you can resize drawable image than set on `ImageView` . find the width and height of your bitmap which you want to set on `ImageView` and call the desired method. suppose your width 500 is greater than height than call method

```
//250 is the width you want after resize bitmap
Bitmat bmp = BitmapScaler.scaleToFitWidth(bitmap, 250) ;
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture);
image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

**You use this class for resize bitmap.**

```
public class BitmapScaler{
// Scale and maintain aspect ratio given a desired width
// BitmapScaler.scaleToFitWidth(bitmap, 100);
 public static Bitmap scaleToFitWidth(Bitmap b, int width)
  {
    float factor = width / (float) b.getWidth();
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, (int) (b.getHeight() * factor), true);
  }


  // Scale and maintain aspect ratio given a desired height
  // BitmapScaler.scaleToFitHeight(bitmap, 100);
  public static Bitmap scaleToFitHeight(Bitmap b, int height)
  {
    float factor = height / (float) b.getHeight();
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, (int) (b.getWidth() * factor), height, true);
   }
 }
```

**xml code is**

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/picture"
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="250dp"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="fitcenter" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/yourImage"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write it in xml

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found the answer buried in a comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6143521/11489088) (credit to @vida).

```
android:scaleType="centerInside"
```

> How about using `android:scaleType="centerInside"` instead of `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`? It would also not crop the image but ensure that both width and height are less than or equal the imageview's width and height :) Here's a good visual guide for scaletypes: [Android ImageView ScaleType: A Visual Guide](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide)

Answer (score 0):

kotlin version of Jarno Argillander's answer used for my app

```
    /**
 * scale the image represented in the bitmap.
 * Refer to [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232608/fit-image-into-imageview-keep-aspect-ratio-and-then-resize-imageview-to-image-d)
 * answer of [Jarno Argillander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030049/jarno-argillander)
 *
 * @param bitmap bitmap of the image
 * @param view imageview where the image will be displayed
 * @see .dpToPx
 */
@Throws(NoSuchElementException::class)
private fun scaleImage(bitmap: Bitmap?, view: ImageView) {
    // Get current dimensions AND the desired bounding box
    var width: Int
    width = try {
        bitmap!!.width
    } catch (e: NullPointerException) {
        throw NoSuchElementException("Can't find bitmap on given view/drawable")
    }
    var height = bitmap.height
    val bounding = dpToPx(150)
    // Determine how much to scale: the dimension requiring less scaling is
    // closer to the its side. This way the image always stays inside your
    // bounding box AND either x/y axis touches it.
    val xScale = bounding.toFloat() / width
    val yScale = bounding.toFloat() / height
    val scale = if (xScale <= yScale) xScale else yScale
    // Create a matrix for the scaling and add the scaling data
    val matrix = Matrix()
    matrix.postScale(scale, scale)
    // Create a new bitmap and convert it to a format understood by the ImageView
    val scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true)
    width = scaledBitmap.width // re-use
    height = scaledBitmap.height // re-use
    val result = BitmapDrawable(context.resources, scaledBitmap)
    // Apply the scaled bitmap
    view.setImageDrawable(result)
    // Now change ImageView's dimensions to match the scaled image
    val params = view.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
    params.width = width
    params.height = height
    view.layoutParams = params
}

/**
 * calculate the dimensions of desired bounding box.
 *
 *
 * @param dp int with dimensions of desired bounding box
 * @return int with dimensions of desired bounding box in px
 */
private fun dpToPx(dp: Int): Int {
    val density = applicationContext.resources.displayMetrics.density
    return Math.round(dp.toFloat() * density)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I just use ImageView inside ConstraintLayout and set adjustviewbound in ImageView to true.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/myimg"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```