# How To maintain the aspect ratio of image?

Tags: android, image, android-layout

How To maintain the aspect ratio of image like 3:4 show on portrait then this image should be convert 9:16 when move device in landscape and image should not be stretched.
Hoe can maintain this please help me thanks advance.

My code are
And this image i want to set on image switcher. How to maintain every image that is set on imageswicher should be aspect ratio.

```
public View makeView() {

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

        imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        WindowManager window = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);  
        Display display = window.getDefaultDisplay();

        imageView.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(
                display.getWidth(), LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
        imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
}
```

Comment: Hope this will help you ,, 

[See this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232608/fit-image-into-imageview-keep-aspect-ratio-and-then-resize-imageview-to-image-d

Answer (score 0):

ScaleType.FIT_XY does not preserve aspect ratio. It's not for photos, but usefull for decorative images. Try ScaleType.CENTER_CROP - your image will cropped to fit view bounds, or ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE - your image will scaled to fit view bounds maintain the image's aspect ratio.

Comment: and what about the layout?

Comment: But it is not maintaining aspect ratio when device move in landsscape

Comment: What wrong about layout? May be you should replace display.getWidth() with LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT? It seems that display.getWidth() as LayoutParams.width is a dirty hack, that works not well in all conditions.

Comment: Ya right, but maintain the aspect ratio in proper way using fit-center working fine for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
```

Use :

```
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.border);
```

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2524243/7438305) answer.