# Resizing ImageView to fit Image

Tags: android, imageview, autoscaling

its a little hard to explain but ill try it anyways.

Im displaying an Image within an ImageView, the imageview is set to use 50% of the ScreenHeight using weight attribute.

Now if the ImageAspectRatio doesnt fit the Ratio of the ImageView, i have an empty space at the bottom and onTop of the ImageView.

Basically i want my ImageView to have a maxSize which is 50% of the ScreenHeight, but to shrink in height if the image in it doesnt use its full height, or at least move to the top of the ImageView.

So, what i did here is i set the View to its max size, and i set the image the way the ImageView usually would. After that i way for the ImageView to layout, then get its Height, as thats the max height i want the View to have.

Then i calculate the Scaling i need to apply. I scale the Image and set the view to Wrap content as it should have the views previous height as a bounding.

Now, this works fine on a Samsung GT-I9000 running CyagenoMod (Android 4.2.2) also tried this on a Kindle HD. But when doing the same on a Nexus 4(running android 4.3) it seems to ignore everything i do.

By that i mean, the image appears to scale properly (imageHeight after scaling something like 53x), but the image takes almost the whole Screen. I dont get why it works on the other 2 devices but on the Nexus.

Is there any new API concerning ImageView for Android 4.3 i dont know about?

```
@Override
public void setImageResource(final int resId) {
    //      this.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 0.5f));
    super.setImageResource(resId);

    getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new OnPreDrawListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resId);

            int width = bitmap.getWidth();
            int height = bitmap.getHeight();
            int boundingY = getHeight();
            int boundingX = getWidth();

            float xScale = ((float) boundingX) / width;
            float yScale = ((float) boundingY) / height;

            float scale = (xScale <= yScale) ? xScale : yScale;

            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postScale(scale, scale);

            Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);

            MyImageView.this.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ));

            MyImageView.super.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);

            getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Ok here is a picture of what im trying to do/doing.

[image: resizingImageView]

Consider the blueish thing the size of the ImageView, and the Black rectangle, the actual Size of the Image. The Blue size is what i get, if i set the Size of the ImageView to width = matchParent and height = 0 with weight 0.5. This is the MAX Height i want my ImageView to have.

Now, it is possible that the Image has a width >= width of the ImageView. in that case, i want to resize the Height, to fit the Height of the Image, so i resize the Image, to find within those bounds and set the Image to WrapContent as the Image is the exact size i want the View to be.

But this is also possible for an Image. 2*width = height
In that case i dont want the ImageView to do anything. Just Maintain its max height and display the give Image.

This works, as i already said on some devices, GT-I9000 and Amazon Kindle HD, but on a Nexus 4 the images that have a much bigger height than width tend to occupy the whole damn screen.

I debugged this and retrieved ImageViewHeight and BitmapHeight. Both stated that the Image and the ImageView is 534 PX high.

I really dont get why i works on the other 2 devices, but not on the nexus.

```
<include layout="@layout/own_action_bar" />

<*.view.MyImageView
    android:id="@+id/drawFragment_iv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/hello" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5" >
something in here
<RelativeLayout/>
<LinearLayout/>
```

Comment: can you paste image what you are desiring and what are getting that will clear the picture of what to do

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232608/fit-image-into-imageview-keep-aspect-ratio-and-then-resize-imageview-to-image-d?rq=1

Comment: thanks a lot, didnt see that even tho i googled for quite a while.

Comment: updated my question as there seems to be some bug i cant figure out

Comment: Can you show us the layout XML? The `android:scaleType` applies to the `setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap)` call and might interfere with the scaling matrix.

Comment: You can use maxHeight and then wrapContent

Comment: thanks, thats the solution

Answer (score 0):

call `setBackgroundResource` instead of `setImageResource` on your ImageView object and it will scale the image to fit the ImageView.

Although it is not an efficient way ti achieve this but if don't have a lot of such ImageViews this should do the trick.