# Pictures in landscape mode on 1920x1200 tablets appear pressed

Tags: android, android-screen-support

I want to place a picture in an app on tablet, with resolution 1920x1200 and the picture is the exact same size, but the problem is the software buttons on the bottom have some height and make the picture pressed on the top and bottom sides... How can I know whats the height of the software buttons, and do I have to manually cut every picture, or can I make it programatically?
Or even better, can I just make somehow the picture take the whole screen, and the bottom end ot just go behind the software buttons?

Comment: You can make the status bar and navigation bar transparent, with your image showing up behind them. There are a number of variations, they're all descibed in the [Managing System UI](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/index.html) document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using this if you want to crop the overflowed part -

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Or alternatively, you can use this if you want to stretch your image to fit the ImageView -

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Also if you want to Fit image into imageview, keeping the aspect ratio and then resize imageview to image, check this - [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232608/fit-image-into-imageview-keep-aspect-ratio-and-then-resize-imageview-to-image-d/8233084#8233084)

Comment: It should have worked. Can you post your xml or code?

Comment: let me just check your link