# Instead of values-sw320dp-hdpi takes values-sw320dp-xhdpi

Tags: android, android-resources

I test with the S2, it should be values​​-sw320dp-hdpi but take values​​-sw320dp-xhdpi. Is it a bug?

**My problem is that Android does not use the correct resource!**

[enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

I have different dimens.xml

Android Version 4.1.2 
240 dpi

Comment: I am suggesting to  use drawable-xxhdpi folder for all devices with 1920X1080 resolution images in it

instead of having mutiple folders.

Comment: I need to scale bitmaps from server

Comment: i thought you are talking about drawable 
it is my mistake that i have not read the question
I have and idea to scale those drawable to sampledummy image,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891177/fit-image-in-imageview-correctly-in-android/25891336#25891336

check my answer 1st one works for you

Comment: I want the height and width itself determine