# Leak of memory with a rescale of bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, scale

I wanted to scale image in order that they kept the same ratio. Thus for example, an arrow has the same size in all images after the rescaling. So I followed [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232608/fit-image-into-imageview-keep-aspect-ratio-and-then-resize-imageview-to-image-d) and it works fine.
But after lost of manipulations of the listview, I can have an `OutOfMemoryError` error. I ckeck the heap dump in DDMS and that's right, the allocation size always goes up. I put some `bitmap.recycle()` but it leads to an error: `"cannot draw recycled bitmaps"`.

I also tried [the official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html), but I had problems, the downloaded sample is not the same as those explained, and I don't understand everything.

Please, can you explain me how to solve my mistake?
Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "some bitmap.recycle()"?? There *SHOULD*, and I mean ¡¡MUST!! be a recycle for each of the disposed bitmap instances. Unless, memory consumption will rise and rise. And, there´s no reason for it not to keep rising even when you dispose all of them if the user keeps provoking the reescale too fast.

Answer (score 0):

`Bitmaps` always stored in the device **Heap Memory** , and your device *heap memory* can't afford that number of `Bitmaps` as may be the way you try works on the same resolution of the image, **So**, at first try to [grow the heap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestApplication_largeHeap) using your app manifest, then try this way to resize your `Bitmaps`:

```
public static Bitmap scaleBitmap(Bitmap bitmapToScale, float newWidth, float newHeight) {

        if(bitmapToScale == null)
            return null;
        //get the original width and height
        int width = bitmapToScale.getWidth();
        int height = bitmapToScale.getHeight();
        // create a matrix for the manipulation
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

        // resize the bit map
        matrix.postScale(newWidth / width, newHeight / height);

        // recreate the new Bitmap and set it back
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapToScale, 0, 0, bitmapToScale.getWidth(), bitmapToScale.getHeight(), matrix, true);  

    }
```

if this don't work either, so, you have to make one of the following:

1. assign to each image a much less width and height.
2. compress the image using something like [ImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).
3. use another device with much **Heap Space**.
4. limit the number of images used.

**HINT:** recycling the Bitmap totally removes it from the Heap memory, So, it's logical to have a `"cannot draw recycled bitmaps"` error, So, if you want to `recycle` it and then use it in your app, you have to store it at first in something like `ArrayList<Bitmaps>`.

Comment: I had already grown the heap in the manifest, and your solution is difficult since I don't know the final size of the image. Thanks for your answer