# The Image Stretched which taken by default camera?

Tags: android, android-camera

Hi I used default camera for my app but after take picture,picture size is stretched.how to get original image size using default camera.

Comment: Put the code also. If it is streching, paste your xml code also

Comment: Intent intent=new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); and used Bitmap Image=(Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Image.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG,500,bos);
    byte[] bitmapdata=bos.toByteArray(); in onActivityResult method to save picture

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232608/fit-image-into-imageview-keep-aspect-ratio-and-then-resize-imageview-to-image-d

Comment: @Pragna am using default camera for taking picture but after i took picture it has stretched to both left and right side can you please tell why?

Comment: ok 1 min you mean to say in gallery it display stretched or in imageview?

Comment: yes in image view it is stretched.

Answer (score 0):

When you take a picture from camera and when you do `data.getData()`, it return the thumbnail image. that is why it is streching.
To get the full image , you need to pass an Uri for the image in the camera intent, to use it to get the full image.

For Example :-

```
try {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(mContext.getPackageManager()) != null) {

            createImageFile();

            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,userPhotoUri);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, Utils.ACTION_REQUEST_CAMERA);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
                    CustomizeCrouton.showCrouton("Capture Photo cannot be launched.", mContext);
}
```

The method `createImageFile()` returns an uri to be used to store the captured image :-

```
private void createImageFile() throws IOException {

    File image = null;

    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";

    if(MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())){

        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
                );

    }else{

        File storageDir = mContext.getFilesDir();
        image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
                );

    }

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    Log.d(TAG,"file:" + image.getAbsolutePath());
    userPhotoUri = Uri.fromFile(image);
}
```

After taking the image, use that Uri to load the image. For that, there are many ways, you can google it :-

```
 Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
```

Comment: how to convert thumbnail image into bitmap show some way please..Thanks in advance

Comment: Read my answer again. It has explained. When you take picture, by default you get a thumbnail image of size around 80 x 80 around(I dont know). To get the full image, you need to pass explicit uri which i did above and after the image is captured, that image is stored at this uri from which you can get the image in `onActivityResult` by the code i have written at the bottom of my answer

Comment: how can i save actual image without passing uri.

Comment: You cannot. you will get a thumbnail if you don't pass uri. Pass an uri. What's the issue.