# How to fix scale of image

Tags: android, scale

I want to have a ImageView of fixed x / y ratio on all of the screens.
for example famous 16/9 ratio.
And I also want that The ImageView be as large as possible.
how could I do it in android?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does the aspect ration you want comes from the image or you want to force it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above answer will alter the aspect ratio.

You cannot achieve your goal by only modifying the xml layout file. You have to do this in Java code.

The basic steps are:

1. read your image file into a Bitmap, and obtain the initial **width** and **height** and **aspect ratio** of the Bitmap.
2. calculate the scaling factors for x and y dimension respectively, and use the smaller one of the two factors to scale your image

   `factorX= ScreenWitdhInPixel/ImgWidth`
   `factorY= ScreenHeightInPixel/ImgHeight`
   `factor= (factorX<factorY?factorX:factorY)`
3. scale your image up using the factor value calculated in step 2

   `Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
   matrix.postScale(factor, factor);
   Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);`

Please refer to this post for a full example: [ImageView fit without stretching the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232608/fit-image-into-imageview-keep-aspect-ratio-and-then-resize-imageview-to-image-d)

Comment: You must explain your answer here and then add necessary references.

Answer (score 0):

You must set  android:scaleType="fitXY" to your imageView.

And if you want your ImageView be as large as its parent, you can write this lines of codes:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```