# Android Image scaling, how to get rid of black stripes

Tags: android, scaling

I'am working on some Android stuff and I have encountered weird problem with image scaling. The image that you you can see in the image below has:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagePreview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/editor_placeholder"
            android:contentDescription="@string/stfu" />
```

And i keep asking myself why are those black stripes present. Can i make it to display the image without those stripes?

SOLUTION:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Got rid off unnecessary stripes.

[image]

Comment: use `android:scaleType`. There are different enums that will do different things. Have a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html and http://www.techrepublic.com/article/clear-up-ambiguity-about-android-image-view-scale-types-with-this-guide/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can do this a few different ways. If you want the image to fit and don't care about the crop of the image you can do something like:

```
   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagePreview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/editor_placeholder"
        android:contentDescription="@string/stfu" />
```

there are various different [ImageView.ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) for an `ImageView`:

> > CENTER -> Center the image in the view, but perform no scaling. From XML, use this syntax: `android:scaleType="center"`.
> >
> > CENTER_CROP -> Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding). The image is then centered in the view. From XML, use this syntax: `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`.
> >
> > CENTER_INSIDE -> Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding). The image is then centered in the view. From XML, use this syntax: `android:scaleType="centerInside"`.
> >
> > FIT_CENTER -> Scale the image using CENTER. From XML, use this syntax: `android:scaleType="fitCenter"`.
> >
> > FIT_END -> Scale the image using END. From XML, use this syntax: `android:scaleType="fitEnd"`.
> >
> > FIT_START -> Scale the image using START. From XML, use this syntax: `android:scaleType="fitStart"`.
> >
> > FIT_XY -> Scale the image using FILL. From XML, use this syntax: `android:scaleType="fitXY"`.
> >
> > FIT_MATRIX -> Scale using the image matrix when drawing. The image matrix can be set using setImageMatrix(Matrix). From XML, use this syntax: `android:scaleType="matrix"`.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) is a nice article from the developer site to help with programmatic scaling

Comment: I used fit start/end and it kinda works. Kinda.. It still has black stripes but they are accumulated on the bottom or the top.

Comment: @Haito try just using `android:scalyType="fitXY"` with `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`

Comment: Well.. Good enough. Thank you very much.

Comment: Well... I found android:adjustViewBounds="true" which made it.

Comment: @Haito yes, this is also a nice helper to maintain the aspect ratio

Answer (score 0):

use android imageview scale type property inside imageview in xml file ..

```
android:scaleType="fitXY".
```

Comment: It destroys ratios and messes the image.

Comment: @Haito then you can use different  type of property like   centerCrop is best option

Comment: centerCrop crops, which is opposite of what i want

Comment: then you should maintain the aspect ratio of image may be use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232608/fit-image-into-imageview-keep-aspect-ratio-and-then-resize-imageview-to-image-d

Comment: If you're updating your answer please edit the relevant information into the post.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan this link is the good and proper answer to maintain aspect ratio

Comment: @vishaljangid If it is that's great, but please put all the relevant info into the answer. Comments are second class citizens and likely not to be read.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagePreview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/editor_placeholder"
        android:contentDescription="@string/stfu" />
```