# I can't see my dice picture when I run the app on an emulator

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have added a picture to an imageView. 
I can see the picture in my preview, but when I run the application, it just displays a red square. 
The image has a size of 256 × 256.
Here is the code

```
 <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/dicepic"/>
```

Image of dice game

[image]

Comment: Check the preview with different screen densities or sizes

Comment: Can you try setting it programmatically: `img.setImageResource(R.mipmap. dicepic);`

Comment: It also looks like you may be experiencing a scaling problem. You could also take a look at this answer and see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232608/fit-image-into-imageview-keep-aspect-ratio-and-then-resize-imageview-to-image-d

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it!

Comment: don't put regular drawables in mipmap. Mipmap is only for app launcher icons