# Resize ImageView programmatically

Tags: android

I'm working with an ImageView and I want to resize it programmatically passing (for example) from a full-screen ImageView to a 50x50. Is there a way to do that?
Different from the one you suggested me to see because I don't need to fit the image in the ImageView but to resize the dimension of the ImageView.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8233084/3780625

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fit image into ImageView, keep aspect ratio and then resize ImageView to image dimensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232608/fit-image-into-imageview-keep-aspect-ratio-and-then-resize-imageview-to-image-d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LayoutParams` to set height width programmatically -

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = imageView.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.width = 30;
layoutParams.height = 30;
imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion use a relative layout and put image inside that has with weight and able to auto resize which depends on the weight. The best way to auto resize even your screen rotates.

I didn't remember which one layout has weight format

Answer (score 0):

ConstraintLayout provides a mechanism for fixing the aspect ratio of a child view. Select the child view that we want to control, and then set the ratio value, we can manually put the ratio that we want to set.
Using constraintLayout makes UI shrink or expand according to screen size without distorting the UI. This is the most important advantage of using ConstraintLayout in UI.