# How to stretch the image in ImageView?

Tags: java, android

I have an `ImageView` and I need to load `jpg` image from SD card into this view. I have following code:

```
mImageView.setImageBitmap(SDCardUtilities.getBitmapFromSDCard(item));
```

`getBitmapFromSDCard` is my function that only make `Bitmap` from file on sdcard. But often an image is small and doesn't fill the `ImageView` fully. How can I stretch the image that it will be fill whole `ImageView`?

Answer (score 3):

```
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

this will make image fill the container

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the `android:scaleType` value for the `ImageView` object.

This link may answer your question better: [How to scale an Image in ImageView to keep the aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521959/how-to-scale-an-image-in-imageview-to-keep-the-aspect-ratio)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
mImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
mImageView.setImageBitmap(SDCardUtilities.getBitmapFromSDCard(item));
```

I didn't personally test this, but I'm pretty sure that it will do what you want. If it doesn't, let me know your results and we can adjust it.

BTW, I found this information [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) and you can see a list of possible values that can be passed to setScaleType [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html).

Answer (score 0):

Never having tried this, i'd say: Set the scaletype for your ImageView, try FIT_CENTER for example.