# ImageView not resizing

Tags: android, android-imageview

I'm trying to scale down an ImageView to be used in a relative layout as a listView row, but the image is just not resizing. Any ideas of what I could be missing?? 64 dip is much smaller than the original source.

```
<dimen name="friend_favorite_image_size">64dip</dimen>

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/friend_user_image"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/friend_favorite_image_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/friend_favorite_image_size"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/friend_favorite_margin"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    scr="@drawable/placeholder_user" />

    ImageView friendImage = (ImageView)rowItem.findViewById(R.id.friend_user_image);
    friendImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.placeholder_user);
```

Comment: When I change my dimens value, nothing happens at all.

Comment: have you taken a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/2524243/1458047 ?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the posts. I believe I figure out my issue. The assets were cut with invisible padding in the images. Grrr. Ended up using hierarchyviewer to figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Thanks for the posts. I believe I figure out my issue. The assets were cut with invisible padding in the images. Grrr. Ended up using hierarchyviewer to figure this out.