# Does Android have Aspect Fill concept similar  to iOS?

Tags: android

Is there any concept related to IPhone Aspect Fill within Android.I want to include this same concept on my android image on imageview. Please give me the code snippet for this concept?

Comment: Look at this. here you can find your answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/2524243/614807

Answer (score 79, accepted):

If you want an ImageView that both scales up and down while keeping the proper aspect ratio, add this to your XML:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

[Look](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2524243/614807) this.

Comment: This answer is not correct as "fitCenter" does not provide same behaviour than iOS "Aspect Fill". You need to use scaleType="centerCrop" instead.

Comment: Does not fill the screen properly

Comment: If Anybody is Looking for a property that is similar to Apsect FIt in ios (that is image will maintain its aspect ratio and would fit at least one of (X or y)) then android:scaleType = "fiteCenter" would do.

Answer (score 29):

I tried fitCenter and it did not work, I ended up using

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Answer (score 3):

Tested!!! `adjustViewBounds` needs to be false along with `scaleType` centerCrop to match `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` behavior of iOS

```
android:adjustViewBounds="false"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```