# evenly distributing icons in relative layout

Tags: android, icons, android-relativelayout

Picture here:

[image]

How to evenly distribute these three icons (with 1dp gap in between and another 1dp margin on both edges) regardless of the screen size ?

I am using relative layout.

Thanks !

**EDIT**
Progress: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcBre.jpg

```
<ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/text" 
                android:background="@null"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"/>
```

still not getting any padding between the icons.

Answer (score 2):

To acheive the effect use (be sure to use `Linear_Layout`)

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
andorid:padding="0.5dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

in each widgets. `layout_weight` is used specify size ratio between sister widgets.

Comment: it says android:layout_weight="1" is invalid in relative layout.

Comment: You cant use it in relative layout. You can just move the three icons in the top row to a linear_layout.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a relative layout for that, use a linear layout.  Set all 3 to fill_parent and a layout weight of 1.  That should work.

If you do need a relative layout for other reasons, put a linear layout inside of the relative layout and put the icons inside the linear layout.

Comment: Yes, I do need relative for other reasons. so, to put linear now, do I have to remove all the icons first ?

Comment: You'd do something like this: 
<RelativeLayout>
    //Other stuff here
    <LinearLayout>
        //Icons here
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: I am struggling to get the padding to work in the linear layout

Answer (score 0):

To each of your icons add the following attribute -

`android:paddingLeft="1dp"` - on the left

To only the last icon add

`android:paddingRight ="1dp"` - on the right

This will give each of you icons a black area around it. You may have to look into scaling that last image on the right, because even with the padding it may not fit.

- http://androidforums.com/application-development/46396-android-supports-auto-scaling-images.html
- [How to scale an Image in ImageView to keep the aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521959/how-to-scale-an-image-in-imageview-to-keep-the-aspect-ratio)

Also, if you want to scroll through those images, then you should use a `HorizontalScrollView` -

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html

Comment: That will provide a 2dp gap between neighboring icons.

Comment: A 0.5 padding will not give the desired 1dp padding on the edges.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display images in a uniform manner, you can use GridView in your layout and pass the images using an Adapter class.

For more info, you can refer developer site:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

For a simple example code, you can refer this link:
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/