# How to change imageview width based on seekbar postion in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am doing one application where I need to change the imageview width based on the seekbar position, I tried using the code below, but when I move the seekbar, the imageview width and height are both changing, but I want change only the width to be changed, the height should be constant. If I set a background to the imageview in xml only width changes, but in my app I have to set the background dynamically, so please, anyone can help me....

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {

   float screenHeight,screenWidth,screendensity;
   private SeekBar mSeekBar;
   ImageView i1;

   int width2;
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms,parms1;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setNoTitle();
      getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,               WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
      DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
      getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
      screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
      screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      mSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);
      mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

      Globalclass.widthnew=(int)(212*(screenWidth/320));
      Globalclass.hightnew=(int)(360*(screenHeight/480));  

      mSeekBar.setMax(Globalclass.widthnew);
      mSeekBar.setProgress(Globalclass.widthnew);

     }

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

    width2=progress;
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Seekbar Value : " + width2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    i1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    i1.setImageResource(R.drawable.frame_one1);
    parms = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width2+50,Globalclass.hightnew);
    parms.topMargin=(int)(200*(screenHeight/480));
     i1.setLayoutParams(parms);

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Started Tracking Seekbar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    mSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress(seekBar.getProgress());
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Stopped Tracking Seekbar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
private void setNoTitle() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you adjust the width of your `ImageView`, Android automatically scales the image inside it to keep the aspect ratio. If you choose a different background color you can notice that your `ImageView` changes the width and height based or your requirements, but the image inside keeps its original aspect ratio.

In order to achieve what you want you have to change the `scaleType` of your image inside. You can do this by adding `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to your `ImageView` in the `xml` file. `fitXY` scales the X and Y independently.

For more details check out [ImageView.ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) as well as this post [How to scale an Image in ImageView to keep the aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2521959/935627)