# Want ScreentShot of each View of recyclerView separately

Tags: java, android, listview

`OnBind` of recyclervIEW:-

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemViewHolder holder, final int position)
{
  holder. tv_bill_no.setText(context.getString(R.string.bill_no_display , 
    String.valueOf(12))  );
    holder.tv_total_amt_label.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.textline));
    holder.lv_product_sub_totals.setEmptyView(holder.emptyview);
    Typeface typeface=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"Capture_it.ttf");
    holder.tv_dist_name.setTypeface(typeface);
    holder.tv_generate.setTypeface(typeface);
    holder.btn_generate_pdf.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   // itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.btn_generate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.btn_share.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    holder.ll.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    // ImageView iv = (ImageView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.bdf_iv_bill);

    Bitmap bm = Utility.screenShot(holder.ll);
    bitmap_pdf_pages.add(bm);

    Log.e("width",""+holder.ll.getWidth());

   }
```

Its throwing an error 
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0`

What I am doing is in `OnBind` i am taking a `screenshot` of each view and adding it ta `ArrayList<Bitmap>` but I am unable to do so. I want a solution where I can take the `screenshots` of `views` of a `listview` separately not in a single go. Others opinions are accepted.

Answer (score 1):

It is throwing an error because `View.getHeight()` (I assume it is being used in `Utility.screenShot(holder.ll)`) only has value after the view has been measured and at OnBindViewHolder that has not happened yet.

So you have to force the measure manually and use `view.getMeasuredHeight()` instead, taking the same constraints as the ones defined in the axml before you "take the screenshot".

For the example I'm taking a width and height measurement of 300.

```
View u = holder.ll;
holder.ll.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(300, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(300, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
u.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
int totalHeight = holder.ll.getMeasuredHeight();
int totalWidth = holder.ll.getMeasuredWidth();
u.layout(0, 0, totalWidth, totalHeight);    
u.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(u.getDrawingCache());             
u.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Sources:

- [How to get the height of recyclerview 's item in “onBindViewHolder”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38765295/6248510)
- [Taking a “screenshot” of a specific layout in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650049/taking-a-screenshot-of-a-specific-layout-in-android)
- [When will MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED and MeasureSpec.AT_MOST be applied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022841/when-will-measurespec-unspecified-and-measurespec-at-most-be-applied)

HIH

Comment: I got ur point ,  i will try it giving a fixed height and width(though it might be an issue because not all `views` are of `equal dimemsion`)  and give you the feedback tomorrow.. :)

Comment: It's not about fixed height or not, it is about measuring before you take the screenshot. You can set "wrap_content" using View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST for example. Follow the link in the source and there it is explained or check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.MeasureSpec.html. Hope it helps :D

Comment: For the example I'm taking a width and height measurement of `300` . What is actually 300?

Comment: AFAIK it is in pixels so if you want dp just do the math with the device display density like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605527/converting-pixels-to-dp