# Android widget size and ImageView from XML

Tags: android, widget, imageview, image-resizing

I have the following widget :

[image: Widget diff Size]

The Image is ok if the widget size w=h , but its streching if different.

How to keep it proportional ? And resize should even work.

My XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/Widget"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/buttonwidget"
    android:src="@drawable/normalwidget"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" >
</ImageView>
```

I would prefer a XML solution and not Drawable code if possible.

Comment: Check this thread [How to scale an Image in ImageView to keep the aspect ratio][1]. It should answer your question. :)


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521959/how-to-scale-an-image-in-imageview-to-keep-the-aspect-ratio

Comment: Thanks alot android:scaleType="fitCenter" is working nice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Samuil Yanovski he did fix it..

i changed my XML to :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/Widget"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/buttonwidget"
    android:src="@drawable/normalwidget"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter">
</ImageView>

</FrameLayout>
```

And all is fine how i like it :)

[image: All fixed]