# how to scale down the image from drawable folder in android?

Tags: android, image, imageview, image-scaling

I am setting a imgage in an ImageView. I want to scale down the image size without reducing the imageview size.  Please guide me step by step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use scaleType parameter for your imageviews and set the value to centerFit or centerCrop. More here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Answer (score 0):

Taken from this link: [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521959/how-to-scale-an-image-in-imageview-to-keep-the-aspect-ratio)

You should also see android:adjustViewBounds to make the ImageView resize itself to fit the rescaled image. For example, if you have a rectangular image in what would normally be a square ImageView, adjustViewBounds=true will make it resize the ImageView to be rectangular as well. This then affects how other Views are laid out around the ImageView.