# ImageView fill width of parent, clip any extra height

Tags: android, imageview

I have an ImageView that's displaying a rectangular image. I want to display a review of an image captured from a custom camera activity.

The issue is that the captured image is larger (in height) than the view and so is scaling by X to fit the Y.

[image]

As seen in the image, there's a white stripe along the right side of the image. What I want is for the image to fill the width of the view and just clip or hide the extra at the bottom.

I've tried a bunch of different configurations but can't seem to get it to work. Currently I have:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:clipChildren="true"
     android:clipToPadding="true">
     <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/camera_review"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:scaleType="fitStart" />
     ....
</FrameLayout>
```

The image is going to be cropped into the square view-port so it's important that the image be displayed from top|left, and fill the width.

One way I was able to get it to work was to put the ImageView into a ScrollView, but then I have to hide the scrollbars, and figure out how to disable scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chnage your code like this. It may help you.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:clipChildren="true"
         android:clipToPadding="true">
         <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/camera_review"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />
         ....
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: This works for me, and I will select as answer in a few minutes (need to wait 10 min before I can?), but can you explain why this works a little bit? I didn't try fitXY because my understanding of it is that that setting doesn't keep the aspect ratio?

Comment: Yes this does not keeps the aspect ratio, but will fit the entire image to ImageView area.

Comment: But, I also need to keep the aspect ratio, or the photo will appear stretched or squashed depending on the camera's capture size, no?

Comment: See my answer including link for more clarification.

Comment: adjustViewBounds together with setting src attribute seems to work

Answer (score 1):

According to Moradiya Akash answer, the image will fit your `ImageView` but no accuracy of aspect ratio. Steve Haley had an answer on maintaining the aspect ratio.

Make sure you're setting the image to the `ImageView` using `android:src="..."` rather than `android:background="..."`. `src=` makes it scale the image maintaining aspect ratio, but `background=` makes it scale and distort the image to make it fit exactly to the size of the `ImageView`
.
More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521959/how-to-scale-an-image-in-imageview-to-keep-the-aspect-ratio)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much for explaining, and pointing to other link. Wish I could give answers to both.

Comment: No problem. If it helps, thats all we do here :) btw you can still vote up

Answer (score 0):

change the tag in your image view   "`fitStart`" to "`fitXY`"

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```