# ImageView scaleType, crop right and bottom sides

Tags: android, imageview, scaletype

How do i fill the `ImageView` with bitmap that maintain the aspect ratio ? If I'm using `scaleType="centerCrop"` it crops the top of the image, I want it to crop the right and the bottom sides. Thanks.

Comment: You can change the scaleType to "matrix" and then move/resize the bitmap in the imageview using the matrix.

Comment: Refer to this site for more info about scaletypes http://etcodehome.blogspot.pt/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html

Comment: have you found a solution ?

Answer (score -1):

You could read into this:

[Link to adjustViewBounds @ Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds)

Theres also a similar question here that has been solved with a detailed explanation:

[Link to solved question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521959/how-to-scale-an-image-in-imageview-to-keep-the-aspect-ratio)