# Android xml height auto like css

Tags: java, android, xml

What is the best solution for auto height in Android apps?

I have an image which is a set size and is necessary for the app. When I set the height and width to `fill_parent`, it puts the image half way up the screen.

When I change the height to `wrap_content` it goes down to the size of the image which is no good for scaling on devices.

Is it possible to have a `height:auto` as if it were CSS, or alternatively set the `margin_top` to be `negative value (screenSize / 50%)`

Answer (score 0):

You can put your views into linearlayout and set whem "weight" parameter
something like this

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:hint="@string/message" />
```

Layout knows weight summ and gives to views their portion of screen

**UPDATE**

[Look this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521959/how-to-scale-an-image-in-imageview-to-keep-the-aspect-ratio) about images scale

Comment: I have put the above inside a linear layout (inside a relative layout) and the image has disappeared now. The order goes Rel Layout > Lin Layout > Image. There is an error on the `layout_height` saying that it will be invisible due to being `0dp`

Comment: It will be good, if you append your page layout and picture with wanted result

Comment: Updated answer, android:adjustViewBounds="true"