# how to keep a layout scaled inside navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, material-design

I am creating a **navigation drawer** for my application just like the **Google Playstore** application. According to material design guidelines the image at the top should be in the ratio of **16:9** [material design navigation drawer dimensions](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/v_2/material_ext_publish/0Bx4BSt6jniD7XzUyQlZIWEFOVkU/layout_metrics_keylines_mobile15.png).
I used a 16:9 image but layout is not stable across different screen sizes and in landscape mode.
How do i do this in xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

to your imageView

[Look this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521959/how-to-scale-an-image-in-imageview-to-keep-the-aspect-ratio) about images scale