# Maintain aspect ratio of imageview in linearlayout weights?

Tags: android, xml

I have this following xml code,

with the following design. my problem is the blue area is an imageview, i want to keep its aspect ratio its 500 x 500. because of the weight its width is getting smaller,... like on the picture.. lets say to 450... but then its looks like 450x500 instead of 450x450 - How to change code to reach that aim?

http://s2.postimg.org/ctlsxajzd/image.jpg

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

 >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" 
          android:weightSum="10"
       >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"


            android:background="#000000"
            android:gravity="top"

        android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/alert_logo"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:scaleType="centerInside" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:layout_weight="9" >


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView
```

>

Comment: Why so many linear layouts? First thing to do is optimize that layout. Use RelativeLayout and get rid of nested linear layouts.

Comment: Replace `android:background="@drawable/alert_logo"` with `src="@drawable/alert_logo"`.

Comment: I need that empty linearlayout for other elements like textviews and so on^^

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to scale an Image in ImageView to keep the aspect ratio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521959/how-to-scale-an-image-in-imageview-to-keep-the-aspect-ratio)

Comment: src did it^^ thank you =)

Comment: what's the benefit of releative layout? instead of liinearlayout?