# Android ui with complex layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to achieve the following complex layout in my android app but with no luck 
[image]

for that i have wrote the following layout xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="8dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_item_title">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_weight="0.6"
                android:id="@+id/list_item_image"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="72.0dip"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_above="@+id/list_item_title" >
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/feedIcon"
                    android:layout_width="16dp"
                    android:layout_height="16dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/cnn"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/feedName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/feedIcon"
                    android:text="CNN International"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_caption_material"
                    android:paddingLeft="4dp" />
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnOverFlow"
                    android:layout_width="16dp"
                    android:layout_height="16dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_feed_action"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_more_grey"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:paddingRight="4dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/timeIcon"
                    android:layout_width="16dp"
                    android:layout_height="16dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/time"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/timeStamp"
                    android:paddingLeft="4dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/timeStamp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnOverFlow"
                    android:text="Yesterday"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_caption_material"
                    android:paddingLeft="4dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list_item_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8.0dip"
                android:text="Why women's watches are having a moment"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:textIsSelectable="false"
                android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_subhead_material"
                android:paddingTop="4dp" />
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/list_item_title">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnComments"
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:padding="6dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_feed_action"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_comment_outline_grey"
                    />
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnLike"
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:padding="6dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnComments"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_feed_action"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_heart_outline_grey"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView >
```

the top most Relative layout that contains `feed source icon`, `feed source name`, `timestamp` and `ovweflow icon` is not appearing at all either in xml editor design mode nor during my app run time.
Moreover, i feel my code is not provisionally written.

**UPDATE**:
- I have followed the solution given by ***r7v*** , i got the following layout which is fine but still have problem with post image as it has to shrink to the size similar to the red box shown on the screenshot 
[image]

Also, i think the layout padding , margins as not as material design standards

Can you please help me on how achieve layout similar as in the attached image?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

check this out cardview

```
 -- linearlayout (horizontal) 
         --- imageview (height match parent , weight 0.4 )
         ---- Linear layout (weight 0.6 , orientation vertical)
              ------ <relative layout>
              ------- textview
              ------- relative layout
```

xml layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- item_feed.xml --> <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:id="@+id/list_item_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="0.6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/list_item_title" >
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/feedIcon"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_search_grey" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/feedName"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/feedIcon"
                        android:text="CNN International"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/btnOverFlow"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_search_grey" />
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/timeIcon"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_search_grey" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/timeStamp"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/feedIcon"
                        android:text="Yesterday"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list_item_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8.0dip"
                    android:text="Why women's watches are having a moment"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="3"
                    android:minLines="2"
                    android:textIsSelectable="false"/>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/list_item_title">
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/btnComments"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_search_grey" />
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/btnLike"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnComments"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_search_grey"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView >
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but still have problem with the imageView (in the left) it has to fill the left part of the card just similar to the sketch above

Comment: I have updated the answer , how is the view being displayed now

Comment: I have attached a screenshot for the view i have got. still have problem in the post image as it has to shrink to the size similar to the red box shown on the screenshot. also i think the layout padding , margins as not as material design standards

Comment: the imageview has fixed width and height , change height to matchparent and width to wrap content and try

Comment: I know that will fix the problem only if i know that the image size is fit otherwise images will be shown on their original size, but what if i don't know the image size in advance and want to scale down to 90dp * 72dp? is there any solution?

Comment: use one of the scale types to scale your image 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: also , check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521959/how-to-scale-an-image-in-imageview-to-keep-the-aspect-ratio

Answer (score 0):

I havent worked with card view, but i assume you can stick a RelativeLayout inside a card view, and the following XML layout should work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="72.0dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="16dp"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Thing1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:minLines="1"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_subhead_material"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
    android:id="@+id/" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="16dp"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton5" />
</RelativeLayout >
```

[image]