# ImageView to fit height, auto scale width, keep aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-xml

I have a layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="0.25">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/reply_icon"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm trying to get the ImageView to fit its height (`20dp`) and auto-adjust the width (while keeping its aspect ratio), however, it comes out looking stretched like this:

[image: screenshot]

How can I fix this?

Comment: I think your code is  OK, your `ImageView` actually respect it's ratio.

Comment: That doesn't help me at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scale an Image in ImageView to keep the aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521959/how-to-scale-an-image-in-imageview-to-keep-the-aspect-ratio)

Answer (score 0):

Add two attributes: ([android:adjustViewBounds](https://developer.android.com/intl/vi/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds) and [android:scaleType=](https://developer.android.com/intl/vi/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType)) to your `ImageView` for keep aspect ratio

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Hope this help

Comment: I already have `adjustViewBounds` in my layout. `centerCrop` didn't change anything.