# Display camera captured image to fullscreen, without losing aspect ratio - Android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-imageview, android-bitmap, snapchat

In my android app, i am capturing image using custom camera. I am able to set camera preview with proper resolution in fullscreen. When i try to set captured image to imageview using `setImageBitmap`, its not looking proper. Either it looks shrinked or stretched.I want captured image to cover entire screen like **Snapchat** application. I try to set `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` but that doensn't work for all devices. Please help me to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Here is my imageview code :

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pictuer_img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Comment: show us your code. and also mention the ratio

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521959/how-to-scale-an-image-in-imageview-to-keep-the-aspect-ratio?rq=1) answer might be helpful to you

Comment: Show us the full layout please.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i make `BitMap`,

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize=8;
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream,null,options);
```

Comment: it stretches image. i have tried with all `scaleTypes` but none of them worked.