# Choose correct image resolution for Android to download

Tags: android, android-volley, android-gallery

I wanted to know that which image resolution is good for Android to download images from server?

Actually I am downloading images from server using volley. If image size increases,then it is taking time to open in gallery.I am using gallery for display images.

If anyone know please let me know.

Comment: http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/designing-for-multiple-screens-alternative-image-resources-part-2.html

Comment: this also helps you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521959/how-to-scale-an-image-in-imageview-to-keep-the-aspect-ratio

Comment: when you download image from the server you are try to use thumbnail image.

Comment: yes its a thumbnail images

Comment: but some of them are taking time to open

Comment: then download 10 images first and download another images on load more option otherwise you call webservice in back-end and save that images in your database and retrieve it

Comment: doing the same thing but when image size is big then only it is taking time to open first time when first time opened then it open fast

Comment: can you send me your webservice url. so i will try  otherwise you use piccaso library

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110957/discussion-between-mahtab-and-damini-mehra).