# Android picture with correct aspect ratio and border

Tags: android

I want to have fixed size box 120x180 dp that contains a picture with correct aspect ratio and a border painted around it.

XML:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:layout_height="180dp"
app:layout_gravity="center">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/game_border"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/pic_lion"
    android:scaleType="centerInside" />
```

Game_border layout:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#55111111" />
        <padding
            android:bottom="4dp"
            android:left="4dp"
            android:right="4dp"
            android:top="4dp" />

        <corners android:radius="6dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

This `scaleType` setting works fine because it fill complete tile inner and background is not overriden. But to demonstrate incorrect aspect ratio I have increased top margin. See picture below. I tried remaining values but they either paint over the border or do not fill complete inner part.

How can I have the tile that has the border around a part of the picture with the right aspect ratio? The picture can be cut. I think that this technique is called center crop. I found it in the Picasso library.

[image]

FitXY deforms picture:

[image: Bad aspect]

Manually painted picture when I cropped picture while preserving aspect ratio. Sorry, it looks ugly but bounty ends very soon.

[image]

Bjorn's answer:

[image]

Rahul answer does not have bottom border

[image]

Comment: did you test `android:adjustViewBounds` with true value?

Comment: I set it to true but it did not help.

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521959/how-to-scale-an-image-in-imageview-to-keep-the-aspect-ratio

Comment: I think I am looking for center crop. This picasso description looks to fit my need:  

CenterCrop() is a cropping technique that scales the image so that it fills the requested bounds of the ImageView and then crops the extra. The ImageView will be filled completely, but the entire image might not be displayed.

Comment: @Leos Literak you want to set an image to a view with the exact aspect ratio. as an example if there is an image view with 50dp in top padding ..you need to show your image in the remaining  space with the aspect ratio without stretched.. is that you want or something else?

Comment: @LeosLiterak  Can you put up your expected output beneath the images with a separate heading ?

Comment: @Leos Literak return home quickly then :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple Framelayout for the background and use centerCrop for the ImageView:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_with_rounded_corners"
    android:padding="4dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

And move the padding into the FrameLayout, so for your background resource file you only need color and corners:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#55111111" />
            <corners android:radius="6dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: I have added a screenshot of your asnwer.

Answer (score 5):

```
<ImageView
android:id="@id/img"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

scaleType="fitCenter" (default when omitted)

- will make it as wide as the parent allows and up/down-scale as needed keeping aspect ratio.

  scaleType="centerInside"
- if the intrinsic width of src is smaller than parent width
  will center the image horizontally
- f the intrinsic width of src is larger than parent width
  will make it as wide as the parent allows and down-scale keeping aspect ratio.

It doesn't matter if you use `android:src` or `ImageView.setImage*`.key is 
android:adjustViewBounds

> **Or**  Using the CardView also you can make rounded corners for imageView.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_5dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#D3D3D3"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/image"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Nice answer. No fitXY helped. The CardView is a nice trick to get borders, I like it. But picture does not respect ratio. I need a crop technique.

Comment: @LeosLiterak Did you checked with `scaleType=fitCenter` and `adjustViewBounds=true` ?

Comment: You are right that the aspect is preserved. But I need complete are painted by the picture. Your solution paints grey area around the small picture with fitCenter or improperly scaled picture with titXY.

Comment: remove `android:layout_margin=3dp` of imageView due to that you are getting gray area around the image.

Comment: if still your facing the issue ,post your image

Comment: It still does not work. I added screenshot to my question.

Comment: Pity I cannot split a bounty between http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293942/1639556  :-( I have three answers I favor.

Answer (score 2):

Having rounded corner ImageView can be a bit of a painful task. What you can do use a library that supports both rounded corners and borders. For example

https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView

If you understand what it does then you can easily create your own ImageView. The trick is to override the onDraw method of the ImageView and clip using paths. You can find some articles related to this topic.

Comment: Cool. I worried that I cannot fix it in XML and I will have to implement it myself. So this would save me lots of work. Bu I am still waiting if somebody knows root source of this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use two separate ImageViews: one for the frame, and another one for the picture. That way you can use the ScaleType "centerCrop" on the picture ImageView, and resultant picture will always be in the desired aspect-ratio with a border around it.

Just make sure that the constraints on both ImageViews are set so that both ImageViews span the parent.

Code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:layout_height="180dp">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/game_border"
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/lion"
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" />
```

Result:
[Picture_with_border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQXSK.png)

Comment: This answer looks very promising. I will test it at evening. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using `ConstraintLayout`, there's this handy attribute [app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#DimensionConstraints) that let you specify aspect ratio dimensions. Here's layout code for the picture below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/picture"
      android:layout_width="120dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:background="@drawable/game_border"
      android:scaleType="centerInside"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h, 2:3"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/vertical_deploy"
      />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: example]

Comment: It does not work. And I doubt it could. This parameter defines a ratio between width and height of the component. It does not influence how loaded image is displayed.

Comment: Yeah I misunderstood your question. Can I have one of your images?

Comment: Take any image, dimensions are not important. Set padding top to high value to deform the image.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:background="@drawable/game_border">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/picture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/pic_lion"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Hope will help you!