# Maintaining correct aspect ratio for windowBackground on Android splash activity

Tags: android, android-activity, splash-screen, launch, aspect-ratio

I am working on getting a splash activity implemented in my project. The splash activity currently loads perfectly, and there's no "white flash" before the image loads - which is good.

My only problem is maintaining the correct **aspect ratio** of the splash screen image.

Here's the theme I am using for SplashActivity

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
</style>
```

**splash.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/pink_grid"
        android:gravity="fill_vertical|clip_horizontal"
/>
```

And here's a screenshot of the result I am getting:

[image: Improper Aspect Ratio]

The black / pink grid image that I am using as the background has uniform squares. As you can see from the image, it's not maintaining a proper aspect ratio (being squished horizontally).

Here's the grid image (1280x1920):

[image: Pink and black grid image]

**What I tried:**

It seems the only way to control the aspect ratio of the splash windowBackground is by using `gravity`. I tried to fill the image vertically and crop horizontally. But this does not maintain aspect ratio.

**How can I adjust the gravity of the splash image to maintain aspect ratio and fit the screen on any device?**

**Edit: Progress based on Raz's answer:**

activity_splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/pink_grid" android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
</merge>
```

SplashActivity.kt

```
class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)

//        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
//        startActivity(intent)
//        finish()
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application>
    <!-- ... -->
    <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

The splash screen is just a black screen now. The pink / black grid is not showing up.

Comment: i am at the same situation as you were. did you solve it? if yes then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, windowBackground will always fill the screen. 
What you need to do is:

Set the layout of the activity to:

```
<FrameLayout 
        android:width="match_parent" 
        android:height="match_parent">
    <ImageView  
android:width="match_parent"  
android:height="match_parent"  
android:ScaleType="CENTER_CROP"  android:src="your_image"/>
        </FrameLayout>
```

The imageView property scaletype will preserve the aspect ratio.

As optimizations:

1. Set windowBackground as transparent (for reducing overdraw)
2. Change the root FrameLayout to `<merge>` - like so:

`<merge>
  <ImageView

    android:width="match_parent"

    android:height="match_parent"

    android:ScaleType="CENTER_CROP"  android:src="your_image"/>
 </merge>`

Comment: I set the windowBackground as transparent <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>. I don't know what you mean by #2. Can you post some XML?

Comment: Sorry, I'm on my phone so can't write any code but you can look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834898/what-is-the-purpose-of-androids-merge-tag-in-xml-layouts

Comment: It's more for optimization actually. You can set a framelayout all the same

Comment: I'm not sure how <merge> is relevant to my question.

Comment: @Joe, I edited my answer. Hopefully it's more understandable now.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work. I've edited my original question to show all the progress I've made with your answer. The launch screen is simply a black screen now. No image is showing up.

Comment: You are switching to the next activity immediately on the oncreate. This will not show the splash screen. Remove those lines. Also, you need to setContentView(your_layout_id)

Comment: I added setContentView, and commented out the intent. The splash screen now properly loads on app load in the correct aspect ratio... however it never transitions to main activity. It just stays on the splash screen.

Comment: Yes. Usually in a splash screen you need to add a timer or based on some event to call the next activity (the code you commented out)

Comment: I appreciate your help, but adding a timer is not a valid solution here. Splash screens should be an aesthetic visual for as quick as possible when the app first loads into memory. I think my solution here may be to create multiple splash screens based on pixel density.

Comment: Not sure how that's relevant but OK. That's beyond the scope of question.

Answer (score 0):

When using vector drawable the following works great:

**drawable/splash.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:gravity="center" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who land on this page but couldn't find an answer:

**[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46436219/14590651) is a solution**.

Basically, you need to change the src from the raw "png/jpg/..." to `xml`, and the `xml` imports the raw image with setting `android:gravity="center"`.