# How to implement multiple "Image add" layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to upload multiple images in my db. My question is how to design below screen to upload multiple images.

First: option to add 1st image:

[image: Image 1]

After adding one image, Add option should move to right:

[image: Image 2]

After adding 3 images, the add option should move to left side in 2nd row:
[image: Image 3]

How to design the layout that will move on 2nd row after adding 3 images. Please help to design the above layout. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Simply use Recyclerview with Gridlayout manager

Comment: use a `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` and add a footer of your `Add Image` icon.

Comment: Is their any example that I can refer to implement this design

Comment: You can also use something called [FlexBoxLayout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)

Comment: `I want to upload multiple images in my db` What a terrible idea. You'd better store the file paths, not the full BLOBs.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this code.this is not same as u want but it will help u

### layout xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.gennext.android.agrawalcars.UploadImage">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scroll1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/submit"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frameLayoutiv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageprofile"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#d2000000"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/cae3"
                    />

            </FrameLayout>

            <GridLayout
                android:id="@+id/lnrImages"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:columnCount="3"
                android:rowCount="3">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/addimage"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    app:cardElevation="5dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="35dp"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/upload_photo"
                         />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/noto_serif"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:text="Add\nCar Photos"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        />
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            </GridLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/noto_serif"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:theme="@style/buttonstylescont"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textColor="@color/actionbar_title_color"
        android:text="Upload" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Activity java file

---

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.vlk.multimager.activities.GalleryActivity;
import com.vlk.multimager.utils.Constants;
import com.vlk.multimager.utils.Image;
import com.vlk.multimager.utils.Params;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UploadImage extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String TAG = getClass().getName();


    //views
    private GridLayout lnrImages;
    private CardView btnAddPhots, addinamge;
    ImageView imageView1;
    FrameLayout frameLayout;


    int child;

    //imageprocessing
    Bitmap bitmap;
    int height;
    int width;
    GridLayout.LayoutParams param = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();

    UploadImagesList uploadImagesList;
    ArrayList<Image> images;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sellcar_uploadcarphotos);
        //uploadimages
        uploadImagesList = UploadImagesList.getInstance();
        images = uploadImagesList.getImagesList();

        // view find
        lnrImages = findViewById(R.id.lnrImages);
        child=lnrImages.getChildCount();
        addinamge = findViewById(R.id.addimage);
        imageView1 = findViewById(R.id.imageprofile);
        frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.frameLayoutiv);

        //get device height
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        param.height = width / 3;
        param.width = width / 3;
        param.rightMargin = 2;
        param.topMargin = 2;
        param.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        addinamge.setLayoutParams(param);

        //add btn click
        addinamge.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(UploadImage.this, GalleryActivity.class);
                Params params = new Params();
                params.setCaptureLimit(1);
                params.setPickerLimit(1);
                params.setToolbarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
                params.setActionButtonColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.actionbarvtn));
                params.setButtonTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textcolor));
                intent.putExtra(Constants.KEY_PARAMS, params);
                startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.TYPE_MULTI_PICKER);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
            return;
        }
        if (intent != null) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case Constants.TYPE_MULTI_CAPTURE:
                    ArrayList<Image> imagesList2 = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.KEY_BUNDLE_LIST);
                    //setImages(intent);
                    break;
                case Constants.TYPE_MULTI_PICKER:
                    ArrayList<Image> imagesList = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.KEY_BUNDLE_LIST);

//                    images=uploadImagesList.getImagesList();
//                    images.addAll(imagesList);
//                    uploadImagesList.setImagesList(images);

//                    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: pickerimages"+imagesList.size());
//                    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: single imagelist"+uploadImagesList.getImagesList().size());
                    setImages(imagesList);


//                    if(uploadImagesList.getImagesList().size()<=8){
//                    }
                    //setImages(imagesList);
                    break;
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image not selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    private void removeallviews() {
        for(int i=1;i<lnrImages.getChildCount();i++){
            lnrImages.removeViewAt(i);
        }
    }

    private void setImages( ArrayList<Image> imagesList) {

        Log.d(TAG, "setImages: single size"+imagesList.size());
        Log.d(TAG, "setImages: check child count before delete it"+lnrImages.getChildCount());
        if (lnrImages.getChildCount() <= 8) {
            if (imagesList.size() != 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "setImages: afterremove child"+lnrImages.getChildCount());
                for (int j = 0; j < imagesList.size(); j++) {
                    bitmap = decodeFile(imagesList.get(j).imagePath);

                    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
                    GridLayout.LayoutParams param = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
                    param.height = width / 3;
                    param.width = width / 3;
                    param.rightMargin = 2;
                    param.topMargin = 2;
                    param.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(param);
                    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    lnrImages.addView(imageView);

                    child=lnrImages.getChildCount();


                    Log.d(TAG, "setImages: childcount"+lnrImages.getChildCount());

                    for (int i = 1; i < lnrImages.getChildCount(); i++) {
                        final ImageView container = (ImageView) lnrImages.getChildAt(i);

                        container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View view) {

                                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(UploadImage.this, android.R.style.Theme_Light);
                                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                                dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.Widget_AppCompat_ListPopupWindow;
                                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.dialogtransprant);
                                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_viewsingle_image);

                                dialog.findViewById(R.id.backarrow).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });

                                dialog.findViewById(R.id.deletebtn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        //Todo : rearrange gridelayout after delete image.
                                        lnrImages.removeViewInLayout(container);
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });

                                dialog.findViewById(R.id.profilebtn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        float screenWidth=getScreenWidth(UploadImage.this);
                                        float newHeight = screenWidth;
                                        if (bitmap.getWidth() != 0 && bitmap.getHeight() != 0) {
                                            newHeight = (screenWidth * bitmap.getHeight()) / bitmap.getWidth();
                                        }
                                        imageView1.setImageBitmap(((BitmapDrawable) container.getDrawable()).getBitmap());
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });

                                ImageView imageView2 = dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageiv);
                                imageView2.setImageBitmap(((BitmapDrawable) container.getDrawable()).getBitmap());

                                dialog.show();

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "please select image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "only 8 images are uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    /**
     * getthis method from this url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521959/how-to-scale-an-image-in-imageview-to-keep-the-aspect-ratio/6143521
     * @param activity
     * @return
     */
    public static float getScreenWidth(Activity activity) {
        Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        display.getMetrics(outMetrics);
        float pxWidth = outMetrics.widthPixels;
        return pxWidth;
    }

    private Bitmap decodeFile(String imgPath) {
        Bitmap b = null;
        int max_size = 1000;
        File f = new File(imgPath);
        try {
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o);
            fis.close();
            int scale = 1;
            if (o.outHeight > max_size || o.outWidth > max_size) {
                scale = (int) Math.pow(2, (int) Math.ceil(Math.log(max_size / (double) Math.max(o.outHeight, o.outWidth)) / Math.log(0.5)));
            }
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o2);
            fis.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "decodeFile: " + e);
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: implementation 'com.github.vansikrishna:Multimager:1.0.8'
imagepicker lib

Answer (score 0):

Layout
camera_lyout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:id="@+id/camera_shipment_fragment"
tools:context=".view.fragment.CameraShipmentFragment">

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="390dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    app:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:text="Click below Icon to take Pictures and then click on Save Button to Scan Tag "
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="75dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="QR CODE/BARCODE"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/add_button"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="75dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttonSave"
    android:text="Save and Scan"
    android:layout_marginTop="330dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

2nd Layout file (item_camera.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:background="@drawable/img"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="TextView" />
```

In Camera.java file start camera intent and on activity result write this code

```
LinearLayout gallery = getView().findViewById(R.id.gallery);
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_camera, gallery,false);
            TextView textView =view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            textView.setText("Image" +value);
            ImageView imageView =view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
            gallery.addView(view);
```