# Unable to maintain image aspect ratio

Tags: android, imageview, aspect-ratio

I taking an image from a gallery and showing it in ImageView but, after setting the image in ImageView, its shape is completely distorted and it does not maintain the aspect ratio of the original.

Below is an image after setting in ImageView. How can I maintain the aspect ratio of the original?

[image]

Comment: Could you pass the image view tag in your xml code? How are you setting the image to image view ? Use android:adjustViewBounds=true.

Comment: Does this answers your question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521959/how-to-scale-an-image-in-imageview-to-keep-the-aspect-ratio

Comment: I have tried `android:adjustViewBounds=true` and `android:scaleType="fitXY"` but  nothing changed